# Guice: what happens when I have excessive @Inject on a constructor

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a class `SomeClass` and a `SomeModule` to register it with Guice.

I found out that the constructor `SomeClass` is only called by `SomeModule`, and that `SomeModule` is the only place where binding for `SomeClass` happens.

This means that the `@Inject` on `SomeClass`'s constructor is not needed since `prop1` and `prop2` are injected inside `SomeModule` and passed to the constructor. And the testing also seems to prove my findings.

My question is that what Guice will do when it sees a `@Inject` like this?
Also what side effect will there be if I have an excessive `@Inject`?

```java
public static class SomeModule extends PrivateModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Exposed
    private SomeClass someClass( SomeObject prop1, String prop2) {
        return new SomeClass(prop1, prop2);
    }
}


public class SomeClass {

    @Inject // unnecessary
    public SomeClass(SomeObject prop1, String prop2){
        ...
    }
}
```

If my understanding is correct, you `@Inject` a constructor when you want to inject objects managed by Guice into the parameters of the constructor.
e.g. if I have `bind(SomeClass.class).in(Singleton.class)` and bindings for `prop1` and `prop2`, it makes sense to `@Inject` `SomeClass` constructor in order to inject `prop1` and `prop2` into the constructor.
But since this isn't the case, this makes the `@Inject` here unnecessary

Cheers

Comment: If you're using the @Provides then yes, it's just collecting dust.  If your company takes a stance that you'll never switch away from the provider, then you probably want to keep things consistent and remove them.

Comment: Thanks @kendavidson .Yes I think it’s be better to remove these ‘@Inject’ to keep things clean

Comment: You need `@Inject` if you were defining a binding in the configure method instead of creating a Provider for this class. 

When you define a binding in the configure method, you are telling Guice to instantiate the object for you. That is when it looks for a constructor with `@Inject` to figure out what dependencies it has to Inject to construct that object. In case of Provider, you are creating the object yourself by passing all the dependencies required for that class as arguments. So, `@Inject` has no meaning at that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting @Deepak's comment as the answer:

> You need @Inject if you were defining a binding in the configure method instead of creating a Provider for this class. When you define a binding in the configure method, you are telling Guice to instantiate the object for you. That is when it looks for a constructor with @Inject to figure out what dependencies it has to Inject to construct that object. In case of Provider, you are creating the object yourself by passing all the dependencies required for that class as arguments. So, @Inject has no meaning at that case